# Iterate through unique values in excel sheet with java

Tags: java, excel, selenium, iteration

I have an Excel sheet like this:

| code | vehicles |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | vehicle01 |
| 101 | vehicle02 |
| 102 | vehicle04 |
| 102 | vehicle04 |
| 102 | vehicle05 |
| 103 | vehicle06 |
| ... | ... |

What I need to do is to take every vehicle of a code and insert them in a form in a web page using selenium (see image). Then take the vehicles of the following code and insert them in a new instance of the form in another tab in the browser...

I can read the sheet with the following code but it is an Excel, not a table, and I don't know how to iterate through the codes to take the vehicles of each one and insert it in the form.

```java
[...]

XSSFWorkbook book = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);

XSSFSheet s = book.getSheet(selectedtab);

Row row;
Integer startFrom = 2;
for(int i=startFrom -1; i <= hoja.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
    row = s.getRow(i);

    String code = row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
    String vehicles= row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue();

    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.open()");
    ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
    tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
    driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(tabs.size()-1));

[...]
```

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Can you please elaborate more, which code will be pick up according to you? two `101` which is duplicate but vehicles values are different, in that case what will happen, which one to pick first one or second one, need all those clarity. A proper expected output what value are you expecting from final excel sheet?

Comment: Thanks @KunduK, I just updated que question.